# With HTML5, How to remove video control in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning how to use video in HTML5, however, I can't remove the original controls using JavaScript. Below is the code

```html
<body>
  <video id='movie' controls>
    <source src='video/example.mp4'/>
    <p>Download video as <a href='video/example.mp4'>MP4</a></p>
  </video>
  
  <script>
    function removeControls(){
      var vid=document.getElementById('movie');
      vid.removeAttribute('controls');
    }
    window.onload=removeControls;
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you just not use `controls`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `vid.controls = false;`

Comment: Thanks, that works. But can you explain how come I can't remove 'controls' as an attribute?

Comment: Im not really sure, maybe the property of the DOM `video` object does not correspond to the `controls` attribute of the `video` element. Such as, `class`, the property name for `class` attribute is `className`. But in your case, Im not sure why, maybe you try `control` without "s" and see what happens, or probably just the browsers